# Exception in Meteor, cannot read state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

So, I wanna display navbar depending on if the user is logged in or not, but while logging out it gives me the exception that it cannot read that property.

That's the error:

> Exception in delivering result of invoking 'logout': TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined

And my code:

```
Logout(){
    Meteor.logout(e => {
        if(e) {
            console.log(e);
        } else {
            this.setState({
                isLoggedIn: !this.state.isLoggedIn
            });
            FlowRouter.go("/");
            console.log(this.state.isLoggedIn);                
        }
    });
}
```

thanks

Comment: You've lost the React state scope inside the logout lambda

Comment: Ooo, so @SterlingArcher what could I do?

Comment: I haven't used Meteor and React together, but you have to bind `this` to the logout method, or don't use an arrow function

Comment: @sterling archer nope. Arrow functions take their parents context

Comment: Where is `Logout()` in?

Comment: @JonasW. it's in a navbar class under the constructor method